# How to execute a page's javascript function in perl?

Tags: javascript, perl

I am trying to extract data from a website using Perl. Below is the description of the site:

- site displays data dependent on a date
- a calendar is displayed that is used to change the date
- upon clicking the dates in the calendar, it calls a javascript function that passes in the date and refreshes the part of the page that displays the data

My question is, how do I execute that JS function so that I could loop through the dates that I need data from?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much easy make same HTTP request from your script and get all data you need directly.

You can record all HTTP requests/responses of your browser by using HTTP Fox extension (for Firefox).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I downloaded HTTPFox and knew the exact request the site made. I imitated this request using LWP and it works perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

There is a CPAN module:

[JavaScript - Perl extension for executing embedded JavaScript](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JavaScript)

But I've not already tested them.

**Original post:**

Take a look at `smjs` it's *Spidermonkey's JS  shell*.

You could pass javascript by:

```
open my $jsout,"echo '$javascript' | smjs |" or die;
print <$jsout>;
```

...

But be care! This take security consideration away!